# Debug XML Config file in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, configuration-files

- Is there a way to debug a XML config file?

Like:

- make breakpoints?
- finding the place in code where the config parameters are used?
- found out which values are and aren't correct? (Strongly typed)

---

I often need new libraries *(new to me)* in C# projects I'm working on.
Most of them uses a config file (app.config or web.config).

I use an incredible amounts of time, just to get some values in these 
config files correct, basically because I haven't find any good way to debug,
what I'm doing.

Mostly, I follow guides on the web like here on stack overflow,
and most off time they do not work, when I just do as people write.
I then look at other examples that are written a little different,
until I at some point get a correct result.

In my normal programming experience I work with either strongly type code (Like C#) or I try to design the code to be debugable (As you need with JavaScript!, if you don't use overlays like typescript), or I do a lot of Unit testing.

But I haven't found a good (and most important, FAST) way to debug XML config file.

Maybe I'm looking at this problem in a wrong way! So I would really like to hear what other developers do, and how the handle this issue.

Comment: I feel your pain, Alf.  Ultimately the config file is just an XML document of values, and being able to debug the library flow based on the config settings is going to be difficult.  The key thing is for the library developer to write some decent documentation...and when they do, then for us to read it.  The only suggestion I have is to get your hands on simple working examples and build up your knowledge from there.

Answer (score 1):

If it's an app.config or web.config...
In the immediate or watch window in VS, you can check out the static class (and property) of
[ConfigurationManager.AppSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings(v=vs.110).aspx)

It's just a key value store, so you can get decent info from it